# Unit Testing ViewModel - Data in returned object is always null

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, coroutine, mockk

This is my ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class MovieDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MovieRepository,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val appDispatchers: AppDispatchers,
    ): ViewModel() {

init {
    val movieId = savedStateHandle.get<Int>("id") ?: 568124
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val movieDetails = withContext(appDispatchers.IO) {
            getMovieDetails(movieId)
        }
        movieDetailsState.value = movieDetails
    }
}

    val movieDetailsState: MutableState<MovieDetailsResponse> = mutableStateOf(MovieDetailsResponse())

    private suspend fun getMovieDetails(id: Int): MovieDetailsResponse {
        return repository.getMovie(id)
    }
}
```

This is the MovieRepository

```
class MovieRepository
@Inject constructor(
    private val tmdbWebService: TMDBWebService
) {
    suspend fun getMovie(id: Int): MovieDetailsResponse {
        return tmdbWebService.getMovieDetails(id)
    }
}
```

AppDispatchers

```
data class AppDispatchers(
    val IO: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
)
```

Finally, my View Model Unit test

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MovieDetailsViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    private val movieRepository = mock<MovieRepository> ()
    private val savedStateHandle = mock<SavedStateHandle> ()

    private lateinit var viewModel: MovieDetailsViewModel

    private val testDispatcher = AppDispatchers(
        IO = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    )

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = MovieDetailsViewModel(movieRepository, savedStateHandle, testDispatcher)
    }

@Test
fun `Loading state works`() = runBlockingTest {
    coEvery { savedStateHandle.get<Int>("id") } returns 5
    coEvery { movieRepository.getMovie(5) } returns getDummyMovieDetailData(5)

    viewModel = MovieDetailsViewModel(movieRepository, savedStateHandle, testDispatcher)
    Assert.assertEquals(getDummyMovieDetailData(5), viewModel.movieDetailsState.value)
}

    private fun getDummyMovieDetailData(id: Int): MovieDetailsResponse {
        return MovieDetailsResponse(
            id = id,
            budget = 50000,
            title = "Encanto",
            overview = "The tale of an extraordinary family, the Madrigals, who live hidden in the mountains of Colombia, in a magical house, in a vibrant town, in a wondrous, charmed place called an Encanto. The magic of the Encanto has blessed every child in the family—every child except one, Mirabel. But when she discovers that the magic surrounding the Encanto is in danger, Mirabel decides that she, the only ordinary Madrigal, might just be her exceptional family's last hope.",
            releaseDate = "2021-10-13",
            revenue = 253000000,
            runtime = 102,
            status = "released",
            tagline = "There's a little magic in all of us...almost all of us.",
            voteAverage = 7.637,
            genres = getDummyGenreData(),
            productionCompanies = getDummyProductionCompanyData()
        )
    }

    private fun getDummyGenreData(): ArrayList<Genres> {
        return arrayListOf(
            Genres(16, "Animation"),
            Genres(35, "Comedy"),
            Genres(10751, "Family"),
            Genres(14, "Fantasy"),
        )
    }

    private fun getDummyProductionCompanyData(): ArrayList<ProductionCompanies> {
        return arrayListOf(
            ProductionCompanies(
                6125,
                "/tzsMJBJZINu7GHzrpYzpReWhh66.png",
                "Walt Disney Animation Studios",
                "US"
            ),
            ProductionCompanies(
                2,
                "/wdrCwmRnLFJhEoH8GSfymY85KHT.png",
                "Walt Disney Pictures",
                "US"
            )
        )
    }
}
```

The problem that I am getting is that the expected data is not matching my local object, the returned data within the returned object is all null. From researching my understanding was that it was potentially to do with these being run on different threads hence me adding the AppDispatchers class.

The returned errors are:

Cannot invoke "androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState.setValue(Object)" because the return value of "com.someone.xmovies.ui.detailsscreen.MovieDetailsViewModel.getMovieDetailsState()" is null
at com.someone.xmovies.ui.detailsscreen.MovieDetailsViewModel$1.invokeSuspend(MovieDetailsViewModel.kt:26)

The comparison of the data:

```
Expected :MovieDetailsResponse(adult=null, backdropPath=null, belongsToCollection=BelongsToCollection(id=null, name=null, posterPath=null, backdropPath=null), budget=50000, genres=[Genres(id=16, name=Animation), Genres(id=35, name=Comedy), Genres(id=10751, nam ...

Actual   :MovieDetailsResponse(adult=null, backdropPath=null, belongsToCollection=BelongsToCollection(id=null, name=null, posterPath=null, backdropPath=null), budget=null, genres=[], homepage=null, id=null, imdbId=null, originalLanguage=null, originalTitle=nul ...
```

I had tried to use `Mockk` to test this but understood that that was not possible and am thus using `Mockito` instead. I am of course using `Hilt` as well for DI.

My build.gradle file:

```
// For local unit tests
testImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.46.1'
kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.46.1'

// Mockito
testImplementation 'org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.1.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.5.2"

//Mockk
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.13.5"
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.13.5"
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-agent:1.13.5"
androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.13.5"
androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-agent:1.13.5"
```

If you're able to please help me to understand and resolve this issue I'd be very grateful!

From further testing I can see that in the viewModel class, the movieId is always the default 568124 rather than the value of '5' that should be returned by the mock.

Even if I force the default to be 5 the returned `movieDetails` is still null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue. Sharing the modified code. Hope it helps someone else.

In `MovieDetailsViewModelTest`

```
@get:Rule
var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

private val movieRepository = mockk<MovieRepository> (relaxed = true)
private val savedStateHandle = mockk<SavedStateHandle> (relaxed = true)

private lateinit var viewModel: MovieDetailsViewModel

private val testDispatcher = AppDispatchers(
    IO = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
)

@Before
fun setup() {
    every { savedStateHandle.get<Int>("id") } returns 5
    viewModel = MovieDetailsViewModel(movieRepository, savedStateHandle, testDispatcher)
}

@Test
fun `Loading state works`() = runBlockingTest {
    every { savedStateHandle["id"] = 5 }
    coEvery { movieRepository.getMovie(5) } returns getDummyMovieDetailData(5)

    viewModel = MovieDetailsViewModel(movieRepository, savedStateHandle, testDispatcher)
    Assert.assertEquals(getDummyMovieDetailData(5), viewModel.movieDetailsState.value)
}
```

The main change was adding the `relaxed = true` line to indicate that this is a relaxed mock but that I may override some methods.

Additionally, to fix the issue with the `SaveStateHandle` value not being returned I modified the handling. Honestly I'm not clear on why I need both the line in `setup` and in my test as it seemed to me that the one within the test is the same as the other one. :/

The final change is that the `SaveStateHandle` call should not have been within an `CoEvery` wrapper since it wasn't within the co-routine.

This website was helpful to me:
https://developersbreach.com/savedstatehandle-viewmodel-android/